# How should this datetime format be interpreted? "20190328012019.000000+120"

Tags: format, time, date-time, date, time-zone

> 20190328012019.000000+120

That's the weird timestamp outputted by WMIC commands on Windows. I assume that `2019` is the year, `03` is the month and `28` is the day, and that `01` is the hour, `20` the minute and `19` the second. I further assume that the number `000000` after the dot means microseconds or sub-something-seconds.

What I am primarily confused about is the `+120` part. Is this "120 minutes plus"? No, it's not. I assumed so at first, but experimenting with it, it didn't add up. It's almost as if it means "plus 1 hour and 20 minutes" for the timezone. But how do you know what means hours and what means minutes?

Again, I made a series of experiments where I tried various "+" numbers, such as "+0", "+1", "+2", "+100", etc., and the results just further confused me. I could not determine what it really is supposed to mean.

Comment: Did you pass in a `/locale` flag into your command?

Comment: It looks to me that the offset (+120) is indeed the timezone offset but it is measured from UTC time. 120 minutes is 2 hours ahead of UTC. Most of the northern part of the world is currently in their "summer" timezone, even the UK is currently 1 hour ahead of UTC (BST).

Answer (score 2):

WMIC command will always return the complete current date and time in format `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.milliseconds+UTC_Offset_in_minutes`.

See [Win32_TimeZone class documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-timezone).

Comment: Corrected. For 6 months of the year, GMT is UTC but yeah it should say UTC.

Comment: I disagree with your last edit.  It most definitely should be a GMT offset, and the resulting value is UTC time.  *GMT is a timezone while UCT is a time standard.*  GMT offset in minutes is the number of minutes off from *GMT+0*.  This is confused by the fact in the 1930's they changed the meaning (i..e Universal Time) and parts of GB still use it during the summer months (which we are currently about to be in).